# Restoring a parcelable Array-list of object in a fragment that contains a map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have a fragment that contains a map. The fragment uses an arraylist of objects for the location and descriptions of its markers that it receives from its parent. The problem is that even if I save the arraylist on a bundle in its **onSaveInstanceState** and retrieve it again in **onCreate** the following error pops out

```
05-07 15:39:55.453: E/Parcel(24252): Class not found when unmarshalling: com.ictcsu.DatabaseClasses.sentdata, e: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ictcsu.DatabaseClasses.sentdata
05-07 15:39:55.453: D/AndroidRuntime(24252): Shutting down VM
05-07 15:39:55.453: W/dalvikvm(24252): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fe72a0)
05-07 15:39:55.473: E/AndroidRuntime(24252): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 15:39:55.473: E/AndroidRuntime(24252): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ictcsu.testapp1/com.ictcsu.viewdata.Activity_Viewdata}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.ictcsu.DatabaseClasses.sentdata
05-07 15:39:55.473: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2070)
05-07 15:39:55.473: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
05-07 15:39:55.473: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3568)
05-07 15:39:55.473: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
05-07 15:39:55.473: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
05-07 15:39:55.473: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-07 15:39:55.473: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-07 15:39:55.473: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4830)
05-07 15:39:55.473: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 15:39:55.473: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-07 15:39:55.473: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
05-07 15:39:55.473: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
05-07 15:39:55.473: E/AndroidRuntime(24252):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-07 15:39:55.473: E/AndroidRuntime(24252): Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.ictcsu.DatabaseClasses.sentdata
```

It says that my class is not found even if it really does exist!. Here is my Fragment code

```
public class Fragment_map extends Fragment{
private static final String TAG = Fragment_map.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String MYLIST = "myList";
List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
MapView mMapView;
private static GoogleMap googleMap;
private selector selectorListener;
private static ArrayList<sentdata> data = new ArrayList<sentdata>();
private Boolean mInitialCreate;


public static Fragment_map newInstance(ArrayList<sentdata> _data){
    Log.i(TAG, "List Size:" + _data.size());
    Fragment_map newfragment_map = new Fragment_map();
    Bundle args = newfragment_map.getArguments();
    if(args==null){
        args = new Bundle();
    }
    args.putParcelableArrayList(MYLIST, _data);
    newfragment_map.setArguments(args);
    return newfragment_map;

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    Fragment parentFragment = getParentFragment();
    if (parentFragment != null && parentFragment instanceof selector) {
        selectorListener = (selector) parentFragment;
    }

    else if (activity != null && activity instanceof selector) {
        selectorListener = (selector) activity;
    }

    else if (selectorListener == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onAttach: niether the parent fragment or parent activity implement OnImageSelectedListener, "
                + "image selections will not be communicated to other components");
    }

}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.w(TAG, "here in OCREATE Of map");
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        data = args.getParcelableArrayList(MYLIST);

    }
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        data = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(MYLIST);
        if(data.size()!=0){
            for(int i=0; i< data.size(); i++){
                Log.w(TAG,data.get(i).gettmp());
            }

        }
        mInitialCreate = false;

    }else {
        mInitialCreate = true;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
            for(int i=0; i< markers.size();i++){
                if(arg0.equals(markers.get(i))){ // if marker source is clicked
                     Log.w(TAG,"Clicked");
                     selectorListener.setlist(i);

                }
                // display toast;
            }
            return true;
        }



    }); 

    if(data.size()!=0 && data !=null){
        setmap();
    }
    if (mInitialCreate) {
        mInitialCreate = false;
    }

    return rootView;   
}




public void setmap(){
    for(int i=0; i<data.size();i++){
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(data.get(i).getlat());
        double longt = Double.parseDouble(data.get(i).getlong());

        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Hello Maps")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE))
            .position(new LatLng(lat, longt)));



        // Changing marker icon

       // marker.showInfoWindow();
        // adding marker
        markers.add(marker);


    }
     markers.get(0).showInfoWindow();
     CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(data.get(0).getlat()), Double.parseDouble(data.get(0).getlong()))).zoom(75).build();
     googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}

public void setview(double lat, double longt, int num){
     //MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
      //          new LatLng(lat, longt)).title("Hello Maps");

        // Changing marker icon
        //marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        //        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

        // adding marker
        //googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    Log.i(TAG, "___Check data:"+ num);
    for(int i=0;i<markers.size();i++){
        markers.get(i).hideInfoWindow();
    }

        markers.get(num).showInfoWindow();


        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(data.get(num).getlat()),  Double.parseDouble(data.get(num).getlong()))).zoom(90).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        data = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(MYLIST);
        mInitialCreate = false;
    }
    Log.v(TAG, "onActivityCreated");
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v(TAG, "onViewStateRestored");
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.v(TAG, "onStart");
}



@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.v(TAG, "onStop");
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Log.v(TAG, "onDestroyView");
}




@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    Log.v(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(MYLIST, data);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

}

I even tried to retrieve the bundle in **onActivityCreated** but still doesn't work. I tried to display in my Logcat the arraylist saved in the **savedInstanceState** on OnCreate but it is not empty at all . I checked on my class and search for some error but it seems ok.

```
public class sentdata implements Parcelable{

private int _id;
private String _data="";
private String _lat="";
private String _long="";
private String _img="";
private String _imgP="";
private int _sntvia;
private String _snttime="";
private String _template="";


public sentdata(){}
public sentdata( String data, String lat, String longt, String img, String imgp, int sntvia, String sntime, String template  ){
    this._data = data;
    this._lat = lat;
    this._long = longt;
    this._img = img;
    this._imgP = imgp;
    this._sntvia = sntvia;
    this._snttime = sntime;
    this._template = template;
}

public sentdata( int id, String data, String lat, String longt, String img, String imgp, int sntvia, String sntime, String template  ){
    this._id = id;
    this._data = data;
    this._lat = lat;
    this._long = longt;
    this._img = img;
    this._imgP = imgp;
    this._sntvia = sntvia;
    this._snttime = sntime;
    this._template = template;
}


public int getid(){
    return this._id;
}


public void setid(int id){
     this._id = id;
}
public void setdata(String data){
    this._data = data;
}

public String getdata(){
    return this._data;
}

public void setlat(String lat){
    this._lat = lat;
}

public String getlat(){
    return this._lat;
}

public void setlong(String longt){
    this._long = longt;

}

public String getlong(){
    return this._long;
}

public void setimg(String img){
    this._img = img;

}

public String getimg(){
    return this._img;

}


public void setimgP (String imgP){
    this._imgP = imgP;
}

public String getimgP(){
    return this._imgP;
}


public void setsentvia(int sntvia){
    this._sntvia = sntvia;
}

public int getsentvia(){
    return this._sntvia;
}


public void setsentTime(String sentime ){
    this._snttime = sentime;
}

public String getsenttime(){
    return this._snttime;
}

public void settemp (String tmp ){
    this._template = tmp;
}

public String gettmp(){
    return this._template;
}



@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}


public sentdata(Parcel source){
    _id = source.readInt();
    _data = source.readString();
    _lat = source.readString();
    _long = source.readString();
    _img = source.readString();
    _imgP = source.readString();
    _sntvia = source.readInt();
    _snttime = source.readString();
    _template = source.readString();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dest.writeInt(_id);     
    dest.writeString(_data);
    dest.writeString(_lat);
    dest.writeString(_long);
    dest.writeString(_img);
    dest.writeString(_imgP);
    dest.writeInt(_sntvia);
    dest.writeString(_snttime);
    dest.writeString(_template);

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<sentdata> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<sentdata>() {

    @Override
    public sentdata createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new sentdata(source);
    }

    @Override
    public sentdata[] newArray(int size) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new sentdata[size];
    }




};
```

}

Please help me. I have spent almost a day on this error and haven't find a solution. I think there might be something wrong with my map but I'm new in using google maps on my project. Please Help.! thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use SharedPreferences?

Comment: I am using a list of objects and the object contains multiple data so using SharedPreferences may not efficient and the ArrayList of object is updatable on user click on other fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use :

```
args.setClassLoader(sentData.getClassLoader())
```

before you're getting data

Comment: Thank you for your response. I followed your answer and have set my bundle, however it did not change anything. Still having the same error.